# How to remove a particular version of Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, enthought

I have multiple different versions of numpy on my mac and I want to uninstall version less than 1.8. How do I find out all the versions of numpy installed and how do I remove unwanted versions? I am using Mac OSx maverick and python 2.7

Comment: how did you install the different versions?

Comment: That is what I am not sure of. One installed using Enthought package and it corresponds to version 1.8 but other version I am not aware of.

Comment: how many python versions do you have? what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: Here is the output :

/Users/ashu/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

----------/opt/local/bin/python

---------/usr/bin/python

Comment: ok you have three installs, try `which python` also to see the default

Comment: what python do you actually use?

Comment: I use first one only

Comment: well the `/usr/bin/python` is your system python  so you can safely remove the `/usr/local/bin/python` and associated directories, having multiple installs can end up being a real pain in the ass

Comment: when you have removed those, you can just use `pip install -U numpy` to upgrade `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your site-packages directory, and remove the versions you don't want. If you're not sure where this is on your system, do:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
```

Comment: I think there is a little more to it, the OP has multiple python installations so this will not show all the packages